# Not able to prepare a training data for my model if my number of categorical variables are not fixed

Tags: machine-learning, training-data

I am trying to solve a regression problem where the factory consolidates products which are included in an order.

I have the total time taken by merge factory to consolidate one order.
Now here comes the problem.

when two products of different-2 quantity are merged together, they take certain amount of time to get merged.But sometimes more than two products of different-2 quantities comes in an order and the merge factory is consolidating that.

I have the total time taken by factory for every order it consolidates.
The number of products to be merged at a merged centre can be any from 1 to n.

How do I prepare training data for my model to understand this?

```
 ProductCode ProdQty  

x1           1                

x2           4
```

The above example took 143 hours

```
 ProductCode ProdQty  

x1           1                

x2           4     

x3           7
```

The above example took 200 hours now.

Now in first example it took 143 hours in merge centre where there were two products of different-2 quantities and in second example three products participate and it took 200 hours.

How do I prepare the training data so that my model should understand it and I can predict how much time the factory will take?

I have lot of other features also but that is order specific but I know how to handle that.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated ?

Comment: What do you mean by `two products of different-2 quantities`? Just `two products of different quantities`? Does that `2` add anything special?

Comment: It will be helpful if you include your code (it is not even clear now which language you are using) and a small sample of your data (what is the data format?)

Comment: No.I meant. Two different kinds of products with different quantities.Ex: HP laptop having 4 quantity and hp printer having 10 quantity.

Comment: @seed: I am giving a scenario which I have encountered in my problem.The problem is not concerned with coding/data format. I want to prepare data in such a way so that my algorithm can understand the scenario and can provide me results.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I get your question now, I thought your code was taking 143 hours. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 ... xn y
1  4  0  0      0  143
1  4  7  0      0  200
```

Here, your dependent variable, `y`, which is the time each package took to put together is a function of quantities of all the `x`s that go into that package. Your goal is to regress the packaging time on the individual quantities. In the first row of your training data, the `x3` and `x4` and so forth values are all zero, because they were not present in that order which took 143 hours to prepare. In the second row, `x4`, `x5` and so forth values are all zero, because they were not present in that order which took 200 hours to prepare.

You can now run a regression of `y` on all `x` values, and when somebody says "I have a new order of 10 `x5`, 2 `x3`, and 7 `x7`, you can just plug these three numbers into the estimated equation and come up with your desired predicted `y`.

Hope that answers your data question. Please comment if you need any clarification or modification to this structure.

---

Addition:

If you have extra variables that impact packaging time, you can add them as columns as well. Say you want to use the temperature, time the order received, number of workers, and who the warehouse manager was (Just making up) to predict the packaging time. You can do this:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 ... xn temp orderTime workers manager y
1  4  0  0      0   20  5AM       5       John    143
1  4  7  0      0   30  11AM      3       George  200
```

Of course some of these new features will require dummification, categorization etc; while your original `x` quantities are just continuous variables.

Comment: This is the same which I thought initially.But Xn in my case is 700+  and stacking the remaining variables its going over 725+. The feature vector of length 725 is going to predict my Y which is way too much.Also I have training dataset of length 6 million.Doing this is causing memory issues. Any other smarter ways to achieve the same?

Comment: As far as formatting goes, I think you are on the right path. The data should follow this matrix structure. When it comes to your other two points, Your #2, number of rows, can easily be solved by reading the data as a Dask dataframe (http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/). Your #1, number of columns, should be addressed by a data reduction technique. Some columns can be correlated, some may not add any significant time (tiny items) hence can be dropped etc. Check out correlations, PCA and association rule learning. But the solution should start by formatting your data as a matrix. Does that help?

Comment: Other approach which I am thinking of :- Like in natural language processing problems we make use of embeddings instead of bag of words likewise can't we make embeddings of products? Suppose there are three products involved in first training example then my embeddings should give me fixed length vector(of size say 50) which could represent those three products in vector space. I am not sure if am right give your views?

Comment: I think the context, the data type, and goal is very different than regression, i.e. what your problem requires. In text mining methods, you work with sentences, consisting of words, and use their vectors of 0s and 1s, representing the existence of words. Then reduce these vectors with different methods. But in your case, you have quantities of each item, not just their binary presence. So I think the matrix data + Dask + data reduction is the only right direction.

Comment: This is what I am stuck into.I have quantities attached to every product which is making it difficult to model it by using embeddings. I know using matrix data  and parallel computation can solve it.But the problem's answer is still not the best answer.Tomorrow I have more different types of products coming in into the factory then again I need to rework on feature reduction and my number of columns will increase. Instead I am thinking how I can represent the product in such a way so that even if  a new product comes then my model can approximate it to a nearby output value.

Comment: For every products which factory makes I have the "parts" involved to make that product.Can we use that somewhere?

Comment: I understand. Say you have `z`s that are the parts that are used to make the products `x`. Say `x1` is made out of `z2, z4, z9`; `x2` is made out of `z1, z3, z9` etc. You can use unsupervised classification methods (clustering, say, k-means) to find which `x`s are similar. Then when a new (newer before seen) `x` is ordered, you can find its proximity to those clusters. And you can reduce all `x`s in that cluster to only 1 `x`. This is a very broad idea but I hope I could make my point. After this step, you can continue to the standard data format in my answer. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user3560077 Please let me know if my latest comment didn't explain my strategy well so I can explain differently.

Comment: I got your point.But I am still working on finding better solution.

Comment: Hi @user3560077 just a kind reminder - Can you please mark the answer as accepted if you believe it was helpful to you?